# Create a array of structs

Tags: c++

I have a problem with my code. It is intended to save the values into a struct array. But 2 things happen at random - 1) Array may be empty or 2) Array may contain only one row of values.

```
struct MacroMas
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int Delay;
        int SemiAutoDelay;
        int ammo;

        MacroMas* Cords(int x, int y, int Delay)
        {
            MacroMas _ret;
            _ret.x = x;
            _ret.y = y;
            _ret.Delay = Delay;

            return _ret;
        }
    };

    MacroMas* temp()
    {
        MacroMas _ret;
        MacroMas* macroMasArray = new MacroMas[107];
        for (int index = 0; index <107 ; ++index)
            macroMasArray[index] = MacroMas();
        macroMasArray[0].Cords(-3, 4, 16);
        macroMasArray[1].Cords(-3, 4, 17);
        // Some more code
        return macroMasArray;
```

Comment: what do you mean by at random?

Comment: Like it is floating bug :D Sometimes can be empty. Sometimes only one entry in array

Comment: But it is compiling xD

Comment: Visual studio 2019

Comment: @H.S. `this->x` etc.

Comment: `Cords()` shouldn't even compile or am I missing something? It expects to return a `MacroMas*` but you return a `MacroMas`. And even if it somehow does, it should just return a pointer to an adress of a local variable, which results in undefined behaviour (Sometimes empty, sometimes correct, sometimes random stuff) Also, you are never really using the returned value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First in Cords function : function will return MacroMas* and you return an object of type MacroMas it's mistake in your Code.

in these two lines you make a mistake

```
macroMasArray[0].Cords(-3, 4, 16);
macroMasArray[1].Cords(-3, 4, 17);
```

Cords function has return value
When macroMasArray[0] or [1] calls Cords its not affect on them.
you need to store them like

```
macroMasArray[0] = macroMasArray[0].Cords(-3, 4, 16);
```

or use this pointer in the Cords Body.

```
void Cords(int x, int y, int Delay)
{
    this->x = x
    this->y = y;
    this->Delay = Delay;
}
```

Comment: `this->x` etc. And the second option is clearly what the OP intended to write. Your first option is a bit crazy.

Comment: Using ```this->x``` results in only one line being stored in array and ```macroMasArray[0] = macroMasArray[0].Cords(-3, 4, 16);``` does not even compile

Comment: for each object that you call Cords for it, you can store

Comment: Yeah. But only first one is stored. Others are ignored

Comment: I try it in Qt5.13 with MSVC2015 64bit it will fill all elements.

Comment: So this did fix your problem after all?