# Creating a array of structs #2

Tags: c++

I am writing this post in reference to my recent one - [Create a array of structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61155029/create-a-array-of-structs)
So, where I've got now is this code:

```
struct MacroMas
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int Delay;
        int SemiAutoDelay;
        int ammo;

        void Cords(int x, int y, int Delay)
        {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            this->Delay = Delay;
        }
    };

    MacroMas* temp()
    {
        MacroMas _ret;
        MacroMas* macroMasArray = new MacroMas[107];
        for (int index = 0; index <107 ; ++index)
            macroMasArray[index] = MacroMas();
        macroMasArray[0].Cords(-3, 4, 16);
        macroMasArray[1].Cords(-3, 4, 17);
        // Some more code
        return macroMasArray;
```

Thanks to John, who got me on the right way, but unfortunately, I can't accept this answer, because this eliminates only "randomization" bug. Now here's a stable problem - In array, only the first (macroMasArray[0]) is properly stored, other array's elements get the same value, as the first one. For example. mascroMasArray[10] should be 1,5,17, but is -3,4,16. Same as 0th element

Comment: "_Thanks to John, who got me on the right way, but unfortunately, I can't accept this answer_" So you edit the original question, with the additional relevant information, and wait for someone to write correct answer, instead of posting a duplicate question.

Comment: Well, `macroMasArray[1]` has what you expect when I run this. Why not show the code for `macroMas[10]` if that's where your problem is?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Posts on stackoverflow are very rapidly pushed down. It's useless to do that, because there will be no answers

Comment: @JasperKent I cutted it out, because it is long and not useful for diagnostics. There's same code but with different numbers

Comment: @Raicha. It's clearly not the same. You are experiencing a problem with `macroMasArray[10]` but not with `macroMasArray[1]`.

Comment: Not only with 10th element. This was an example. It is happening with all of them

Comment: @Raicha As I said, I ran the code and I'm  not getting the problem with `macroMasArray[1]`

Comment: Here is example. With element 1 - https://prnt.sc/rxbh1j And with Element 10 - https://prnt.sc/rxbhcd It is happening to all the elements. They are just getting the same values of the 0th one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're simply misunderstanding the debugger. You are always looking at element zero. The other elements have the correct values, but you are not looking at them.

Because you've declared `macroMasArray` as a pointer to `MacroMas` the debugger presumes it's intended only to point to a single object.

You need to specifically type in the watch window which element you want, e.g.

`macroMasArray[1]`

or make sure you highlight the entire element, including the index.